# Ergonomic Standing Mats - Good vs Bad?

Tags: health, ergonomics

I recently began a new position with a Sit/Stand desk setup.  Initially I did not have a mat to stand on while using the standing function of the desk, so I was on hard linoleum.  I found a mat in a storage area that has some cushion but for whatever reason I actually feel more comfortable standing on the hard floor rather than the mat.  I do not know if this mat was "Made" for ergonomic standing so-to-speak.  So my question is:

-Are there some types of mats that would not be beneficial when standing while working?

**OR**

-Am I just accustomed to standing on the hard floor and should reacquaint myself on the mat regardless?

Comment: You should probably just do whatever's most comfortable for you, or talk to a medical provider if you're unsure about the long term impact.

Comment: If the mat is too soft, it could put extra pressure on your ankle muscles and knees. Maybe you could buy an ergonomic mat and try it for a week.  If you still feel like the hard floor is more comfortable, return it.

Comment: A couple of nurses told me once that they would change their footwear partway through the day - slightly wider and slightly lower heel... they found it helped...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Initially I did not have a mat to stand on while using the standing function of the desk, so I was on hard linoleum. I found a mat in a storage area that has some cushion but for whatever reason I actually feel more comfortable standing on the hard floor rather than the mat.

This seems like madness to me - you (seem like) you were fine standing on the hard floor, but thought you should try using a mat. You found a mat to try using, but it's noticeably less comfortable than just standing on the floor. So why on earth would you continue using the mat?!

It is of course great to be thinking about ergonomics, health, posture etc. as part of your working day, but you really can do more harm than good if you overthink it. I find keyboard / mouse wrist rests for instance absolutely knacker my wrists by holding them in a position that I'm really not used to. Others find the opposite.

There's zero point in standing on something that's much less comfortable, just because some other people may find it more comfortable for them. Ditch the mat!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I will continue standing on the floor haha There may be more concern further down the road, with this position.  Again, thank you for your help and entertaining guidance berry